# Does copy of unordered_map will have exactly same buckets

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map

As far as I understand, amount of buckets in `unordered_map` increases accidentally while filling of `unordered_map`.

If I perform copy of `unordered_map` (to another `unordered_map`) it is guaranteed there will be exactly same pairs. But will they be in the same buckets? Will amount of buckets will be the same?

I don't know bucket's creation mechanism, and didn't find short explanation, how it have to be implemented in standard. But if buckets amount may rely on sequence of insertions, allocation and etc, then after copying we may get different amount of buckets, or different distribution in there (even if items will be the same). Is it true? Both for boost's implementation and for gcc's standard implementation?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about the implementation details too much. Library implementers should. Chances are you don't need to know the _creation mechanism_.

Comment: @Ron I agree, but to proof that implementation with unordered_map works better in my specific case, and to discover what is going on behind the scene on real data, I have to print it's structure out.
But because printing takes long time, and `unordered_map` is shareable, I want to copy it and then print out the copy.
But I need to be sure it will have the same structure.

Comment: it has the same "observable structure" if your code depends on implementation details, then you are doing something wrong

Comment: Don't use `unordered_map` in a way where the order of elements makes any difference to your program. Don't think that the "order" you get when debug printing is **the** order, it is **one possible** order

Comment: `unordered_map` has *public* bucket's interface. All I've been asking -- does it guaranteed, that result of calls of this *public* interface will be same from copy as from original.

Comment: @user463035818 exactly to avoid dependency on implementation I need to get answer on my question: will *public* bucket interface of *copy* return the same or not.

Comment: @Caleth I did ask about buckets, not order of elements. `unordered_map` have buckets interface. I've ask will it return the same for copy as for original map.
Because it is not obvious.

Comment: yeah sorry, my comment was kinda stupid. I would expect that if `b` is a copy of `a` such that `a==b` then also eg `a.bucket_count() == b.bucket_count()` should hold, otherwise `==` and copying would be rather counterintuitive, though I also dont know for sure

Comment: @user463035818 I don't think that's the case

Comment: @Caleth I am just saying that if my assumption doesnt hold then it is counterintuitive, though there are many things that are counterintuitive for me but they still are like that :P

Comment: @user463035818 yes, exactly, I wonder the same way, it's very counter-intuitive.

Comment: actually i wonder if the copy has same hash function, same predicate and same max load factor, if it wont implicitly also have same buckets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The max load factor, but not the "current" load factor are specified as being copied when an `unordered_map` is copied.

Both the entry for copy construction and copy assignment include the following

> In addition to the requirements of Table 64, copies the hash function,
>   predicate, and maximum load factor.

[`[unord.req]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.req#tab:HashRequirements)

In general this means there may be a different count of buckets, and thus a different distribution of elements into buckets in a copy.

Comment: Thank you for such explanation. Then it seems not good idea to copy the unordered_map to get know what is happening with buckets )

Comment: @Arkady Yes. I can easily imagine a case like "original has `load_factor` of 0.01, copy has `load_factor` of 0.75" where you copy from a map that used to be much bigger and end up with a more sensibly distributed bucket-set